# Property attribute in continuation class does not match the primary class

Tags: ios, iphone

In `MyClass.h`, I do:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) CustomGridView *gridView;
```

and In `MyClass.m`, I do:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, assign) CustomGridView *gridView;
```

However, I am getting a warning:

Property attribute in continuation class does not match the primary class

Can somebody tell me what I am missing here and how to silence the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, readwrite) CustomGridView *gridView;
```

You can't have `weak` and `assign` in the same property as they are both trying to specify the write type. What you have missed is the read/write access capability.

Comment: Sorry.. I am getting Error when i have changed like that.. illegal redeclaration of property...

Comment: Show a bit more code around your properties then. If the original is readonly then you can only specify readwrite as different in the continuation.

Comment: Ohhh..  I have got the point.. I need to change assign to readwrite.. Yes it has done... .. Thanks Wain.. :)

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to duplicate Instance in `.h` and `.m` files ?

if you want to make your instance (gridView) `readonly` and need to access to instance (gridView) inside .m file you just need to override `setGridView:(CustomGridView *)` method for your instance (gridView) that's all.